# Different result from omreport command and snmpwalk command

Tags: snmp, monitor

I want to find right OID for temperature cpu use in zabbix. 
I use command snmpwalk.

```
#snmpwalk -c public -v2c 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10892.1
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.1.700.20.1.8.1.1 = STRING: "Mainboard MB Temp"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.1.700.20.1.8.1.2 = STRING: "Front Panel FP Temp"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.1.700.20.1.8.1.3 = STRING: "BP Temp"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.1.700.20.1.8.1.4 = STRING: "CPU0 Temp"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.1.700.20.1.8.1.5 = STRING: "CPU1 Temp"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.1.700.20.1.8.1.6 = STRING: "DIMM Temp"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.1.700.20.1.8.1.7 = STRING: "IOH Temp"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.1.700.20.1.10.1.1 = INTEGER: 750
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.1.700.20.1.10.1.2 = INTEGER: 500
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.1.700.20.1.10.1.3 = INTEGER: 550
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.1.700.20.1.10.1.4 = INTEGER: 1020
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.1.700.20.1.10.1.5 = INTEGER: 1020
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.1.700.20.1.10.1.6 = INTEGER: 1000
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.1.700.20.1.10.1.7 = INTEGER: 1050
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.1.700.20.1.11.1.1 = INTEGER: 700
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.1.700.20.1.11.1.2 = INTEGER: 450
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.1.700.20.1.11.1.3 = INTEGER: 520
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.1.700.20.1.11.1.4 = INTEGER: 980
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.1.700.20.1.11.1.5 = INTEGER: 980
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.1.700.20.1.11.1.6 = INTEGER: 950
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.1.700.20.1.11.1.7 = INTEGER: 950
```

Very much OID about temperature CPU 1 and CPU 2. What's right value i should use in zabbix ?

omreport command.

```
#omreport chassis temps
    Temperature Probes Information

    ------------------------------------
    Main System Chassis Temperatures: Ok
    ------------------------------------

    Index                     : 0
    Status                    : Ok
    Probe Name                : Mainboard MB Temp
    Reading                   : 44.0 C
    Minimum Warning Threshold : [N/A]
    Maximum Warning Threshold : 70.0 C
    Minimum Failure Threshold : [N/A]
    Maximum Failure Threshold : 75.0 C

    Index                     : 1
    Status                    : Ok
    Probe Name                : Front Panel FP Temp
    Reading                   : 17.0 C
    Minimum Warning Threshold : [N/A]
    Maximum Warning Threshold : 45.0 C
    Minimum Failure Threshold : [N/A]
    Maximum Failure Threshold : 50.0 C

    Index                     : 2
    Status                    : Ok
    Probe Name                : BP Temp
    Reading                   : 21.0 C
    Minimum Warning Threshold : [N/A]
    Maximum Warning Threshold : 52.0 C
    Minimum Failure Threshold : [N/A]
    Maximum Failure Threshold : 55.0 C

    Index                     : 3
    Status                    : Ok
    Probe Name                : CPU0 Temp
    Reading                   : 80.0 C
    Minimum Warning Threshold : [N/A]
    Maximum Warning Threshold : 98.0 C
    Minimum Failure Threshold : [N/A]
    Maximum Failure Threshold : 102.0 C

    Index                     : 4
    Status                    : Ok
    Probe Name                : CPU1 Temp
    Reading                   : 78.0 C
    Minimum Warning Threshold : [N/A]
    Maximum Warning Threshold : 98.0 C
    Minimum Failure Threshold : [N/A]
    Maximum Failure Threshold : 102.0 C

    Index                     : 5
    Status                    : Ok
    Probe Name                : DIMM Temp
    Reading                   : 51.0 C
    Minimum Warning Threshold : [N/A]
    Maximum Warning Threshold : 95.0 C
    Minimum Failure Threshold : [N/A]
    Maximum Failure Threshold : 100.0 C

    Index                     : 6
    Status                    : Ok
    Probe Name                : IOH Temp
    Reading                   : 72.0 C
    Minimum Warning Threshold : [N/A]
    Maximum Warning Threshold : 95.0 C
    Minimum Failure Threshold : [N/A]
    Maximum Failure Threshold : 105.0 C
```

Sorry about my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MIB file from Dell you should be using:    `1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10892.1.700.20.1.6` which is `iso.org.dod.internet.private.enterprises.dell.server3.baseboardGroup.thermalGroup.temperatureProbeTable.temperatureProbeTableEntry.temperatureProbeReading.` The description of this MIB Object states:

This attribute defines the reading for a temperature probe of type other than temperatureProbeTypeIsDiscrete.  When the value for temperatureProbeType is other than temperatureProbeTypeIsDiscrete, the value returned for this attribute is the temperature that the probe is reading in tenths of degrees Centigrade.  When the value for temperatureProbeType is temperatureProbeTypeIsDiscrete, a value is not returned for this attribute.